# How to access a hidden Dom Element with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HTML Div (I'm using Twitter Bootstrap to hide-show `div2`) looking like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="div1">
  <button id="mybtn">Button</button>
  <div id="div2" class="modal hide fade span12" style="display: none;">
    <button id="anotherButton" data-char="">AnotherButton</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

With jQuery im trying to change the Value of `data-char` while im clicking on `mybtn`. But without success cause `div2` is hidden. `console.log($('#anotherButton'));` return an empty array.

Is there a way to access hidden DOM with jQuery or Javascript?

**Edit: **
By trying this dont work better , return `undefined`:

```
$('#mybtn').live('click', function(e) 
{
    //or e.preventDefault();
    $('#anotherbutton').attr("data-char", "assigned");
    alert($('#anotherbutton').attr("data-char"));
});
```

Comment: Make sure you've wrapped your code inside a DOM ready handler.

Comment: it doesn't matter if its hidden, it just matters if its on the page. If `console.log($('#anotherButton'));` really returns nothing than its either not on the page or there is a typo in the selector.

Comment: Let's see more of the code. If the element is simply not visible, but still part of the DOM, this should work correctly.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KYRAP/1/ works fine

Comment: Which browser do you use? It's seems like a bug — I agree with @AnthonyGrist.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté This obviously applies if you apply the click handler in code, instead of in HTML. So a (better) solution is then to effectively put the event handler in HTML.

Comment: Actually, jQuery doesn't care the element hidden or not unless you have some special treatment to the hidden elements. There might something wrong with your DOM.

Comment: My Browser is Chrome... i updated my DOM! Thx

Comment: @RandyMarsh Not sure what you meant, by putting the handler in the HTML do you mean inline JS `<tag onclick="myFunction()"`? Take a look at [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Yes. I always use inline (HTML) event handlers when I can. It's much simpler, at least in my case.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté it is already into a DOM ready handler.

Comment: @RandyMarsh Yes, I'm sure it works for most cases, nowadays I prefer to take an Unobtrusive approach for a couple reasons: Separation of behavior from markup (not only looks better, it won't generate an "undefined function" error if you click in an element with `onclick` before a script loads), it doesn't evaluate HTML attributes to JS properties, you can have multiple event handlers for the same element for the event and I find it more organized and maintainable to have all the handlers attached through jQuery. @OP Make a http://fiddle.net maybe? `.live` is deprecated but it should work.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Yes, I too separate content (HTML) from behaviour (JS), but only in projects (when I apply all my own conventions and procedures). But when I have to code quick and dirty (and not part of a bigger project), I use those inline handlers. In fact, I seldom really write HTML/JS. I have a PHP library (I wrote it for myself) that does that for me (inspired by Apple's Cocoa Bindings and Core Data).

Comment: I see. I've used inline JS until not too long ago as well, I guess you just start writing unobtrusively as you spend time reading SO's JS/jQuery sections. `:P`

Comment: @trouble If none of the submitted answers work, the problem *might* be somewhere else. Is the button generated through JS/Ajax?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté nope! just a HTML writted DOM!

Comment: Wow, I just went to test it, and really it is returning `undefined`. Now that's interesting.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté isnt? :D i never see such js "troubles" before...

Comment: I found one issue with your question's code, your ID is `anotherButton` but you're passing `anotherbutton` into jQuery. You forgot to capitalize the `B`. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/xLwSa/) `=]` Make sure to check the capitalization of the rest of your `id`s/code.

Comment: Weird though, if you copied the answers' code directly to your file and refreshed the page, it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `data` method will not work on elements which are in hidden state. You should use `attr` method.

This should work fine

```
$(function(){
  $("#mybtn").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
        $("#anotherButton").attr("data-char","new value");
  });    
});
```

Working sample http://jsfiddle.net/kshyju/a7Cua/4/

Comment: Great Answer! the `e.preventDefault` got me choose your answer! Thx

Answer (score 3):

You can assign it

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/LVvAz/4/)

```
$(function(){
    $('#anotherButton').attr('char', "assigned");
    alert($('#anotherButton').attr('char'));
});​
```

on Button click

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/LVvAz/3/)**

```
$(function(){
   $('#anotherButton').attr('data-char', "assigned");
   alert($('#anotherButton').attr('data-char'));
});​
```

Comment: The attribute needs to be 'data-char', not 'char'.

Comment: When i use it! its return `undefined` :(

Answer (score 1):

The fact that it is hidden changes nothing. The problem is probably that the js code is before the button HTML. Either put it after, or put it in a listener like `$(document).ready()` to make sure it has been processed when your try to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$(button:hidden)`

This usually works for things like this,

Source:http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/